# Sort through an csv file and copy only the rows with an keyword in the header

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple csv files, which are separated by an \t (TAB).
In each file there are rows of data with an timeline at the left of it
Attention: multiple data sets can have the same timeline! No pattern detectable!

I want to loop through all the files and in each file i want to loop through each header (word)
Then I want to copy the data row with (for example: I51) in the headers name (I51_RH_T) into a new file (called I51) with the corresponding timeline!
I also want to cycle through multiple keywords for the header!

This is what i managed to do:

```
import re, csv, os, 

keywords = ["I01", "I02", "I03"]

Input_Dir = "E:/MA/05_Sensordaten/Sensordaten txt/"
files = os.listdir(Input_Dir)

i = 0
zz = 0

for each in keywords:
    keyword = str(keywords[i])

    #print(files)
    for file in files:

        if zz <= len(files) -1:
            #print(files[zz])
            file_and_path = Input_Dir + files[zz]
            with open(file_and_path, "r") as csv_file:
                csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = "\t")
                #print(csv_file)
                with open("G:/MA/05_Sensordaten/Sensordaten sortiert/Aufbau" + keyword + ".txt", "w") as new_file:
                    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=" ")  # \t = TAB
                    j = 0
                    for words in csv_reader:
                        if j <= 400:
                            j += 1
                            while re.match(keyword, words[j]):
                                print(words[j])
                                j += 1
                        else:
                            break
        zz += 1
    i += 1
```

Right now I get the error that the list index is out of range!
Whats missing in the code is the part where i copy the header with the corresponding timeline in the new file!

the csv files i want to extract the data looks like this:

```
timeline0 I51_Rh_T I54_Rh_Rh I57_T ........
01.10.20100:00 8,47 54,67 20,54 ......
..................
```

Any help would be welcomed!

Sincerely Daniel

Answer (score 0):

```
for word in csv_reader:
    x = re.search(keyword, word) #Sucht Aufbau in csv_reader
    print(x)
```

Here you are getting dictionary object in `word`
You have to add one more loop for keys or values from this dictionary e.g.

```
for word in csv_reader:
    for key in word.keys():
        x = re.search(keyword, key) #Sucht Aufbau in csv_reader
        print(x)
```

Comment: However, if `keyword` is not a regex pattern but a mere literal string, there is no point using `re`, `if keyword in key: print(keyword)` will suffice.